# How to match beginning of file name using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am attempting to modifying my `.htaccess` file within a specific directory. If a web user attempts to find any file in this directory that may be named like the following options, I want them to be redirected back to home. Below are some file name examples.

- `/cat_1234.pdf`
- `/cat_blahbla.doc`
- `/cat_$9989&428.jpg`
- `/cat_-309bn-020n.webp`

...how can I tell my `RewriteCond` to look out for these patterns?  Here was my best attempt, which I thought would work, but it doesn't...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^cat_([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)\.(pdf|doc|jpg|webp) [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please question the `<IfModule mod_rewrite>` in this. It's often recommended because it means "a missing module shouldn't cause the server to not work at all", but it also means if you deploy your software on a server that hasn't `mod_rewrite` enabled, your `cat_*` files are completely unprotected.

Comment: For starters, it doesn't look like that regex will match the hyphen in your fourth example. On the other hand, it will match an underscore that you don't appear to need.

Comment: Examples don't make a pattern. Describe the patterns more specifically. Is any character allowed between `cat_` and the extension? Or only specific ones? Do they depend on the extension? Does it matter if the regular expression matches **anything** starting with `cat_`? Does the extension actually matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've not stated the "specific directory" in which the `.htaccess` file and files you are protecting is located? (Although that shouldn't matter if we rework the rule.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^cat_([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)\.(pdf|doc|jpg|webp) [NC]
> RewriteRule . /index.php [R=302,L]
> ```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path (including the slash prefix), so this would normally need to include the "specific directory", not just the filename (unless you adjust the regex). You have a start-of-string anchor on the regex (although you have omitted the end-of-string anchor) so this *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) will never match.

Your regex would also fail to match your 3rd and 4th examples because your regex character class (`[0-9a-zA-Z_]`) omits the special characters `$`, `&` and `-` that are present in these filenames. Although I would surmise you do not need to be so specific and catching `cat_<anything>.pdf` (for example) would be OK.

However, you do not need a separate *condition* here. It is easier and more efficient to just use the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, which matches *relative* to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file (and excludes the slash prefix), so you do not need to worry about the rest of the URL-path.

I also doubt that you should be redirecting to `/index.php`. Should this not be simply `/` (the root directory) and allow the directory index (ie. `index.php`) to be served by mod_dir? Is that not your canonical URL?

Try the following instead, in the `.htaccess` file in the directory you are protecting.

```
RewriteRule ^cat_[^/]+\.(pdf|doc|jpg|webp)$ / [R=302,L]
```

This regex is perhaps slightly more broad than it needs to be, but that also makes it simpler. ie. `[^/]` matches anything that is not a `/` (path separator).

And no need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper, unless this rule is entirely optional.

---

However, instead of redirecting to the homepage (which is confusing for users  and unnecessary for bots) I would simply block (with a 403 Forbidden) such requests instead. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "^cat_[^/]+\.(pdf|doc|jpg|webp)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: MrWhite, thank you for the learning curve on this process. This was a major help for me.

Comment: @klewis If things like `cat_.docx` are also restricted then consider using this regex: `^cat_[^/]*\.(pdf|docx?|jpe?g|webp)$`

Comment: @klewis Also, I prefer one-liners and think a 404 would be better than a 403. `RewriteRule ^cat_[^/]*\.(pdf|docx?|jpe?g|webp)$ - [R=404,NC,L]`. A redirect or forbidden reveals that the asset exists, a 404 at least masks the existence.

Comment: Does it actually make sense to allow other extensions? Otherwise just `^cat_` (without anything after) would be enough.

Comment: @DidierL `^cat_[^/]*$`